# 'City' is detected as keyword in email when opened in iPhone

Tags: php, ios, safari

I have created API to send mail in PHP. Below is my code

```
$content = $content."<br/><b>Address : </b>".$fromUser["address"];
$content = $content."<br/><b>City : </b>".$fromUser["city"];

$to = 'abc@gmail.com';

include('PhpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "####";
$mail->Password = "####";
$mail->setFrom("support@abc.io","abc");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = 'Test';

$mail->MsgHTML($content);

if ($mail->Send()) {
   return 1;
} else {
   return 0;
}
```

I am receiving email but the keyword 'City' in content is showing hyperlinked. I want to remove that.

[image: Screenshot of email, I am recieving]

[Note : If I write 'City1' instead of 'City', the link gets removed]

Comment: While the question is detailed, i'm missing vital information. The content of `$content` echoed as HTML. But presumably.. i think that  `$fromUser['address']` needs a `</a>`

Comment: I have included the from address as shown above, but still the same issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Your $fromUser["address"] is beginning with <a> tag but there's no ending of the tag within the variable.

One way is to add stript_tags() for the output.

```
$content = $content."<br/><b>Address : </b>".strip_tags($fromUser["address"]);
$content = $content."<br/><b>City : </b>".strip_tags($fromUser["city"]);
```

The better way would be strip tags already when filling the $fromUser varialbe with data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried this code, but its not working for me.

Comment: Can you var_dump $content and $fromUser after the 2nd line of your example?

Comment: $content is an array having key value pairs in it and 
$fromUser is a string

Comment: According to the code, I guess you just wrote it the other way here to the comment. Can you post the content of these variables? Just do var_dump($content); and var_dump($fromUser);

Comment: $content is an array having key value pairs in it and 
$fromUser is a string -> content of var_dump is quite long to post here

I have figured that the issue I am facing is due to $fromUser["address"], if i write <pre>$fromUser["address"]</pre>, issue gets solved but formatting gets disturbed

Comment: $content can't be an array right after you add a string to it, since PHP autocasts it into string. --- Use pastebin.com to paste longer source codes. --- I wouldn't recommend using <pre> for content that should go into e-mail body